# Error "An SMTP To address is required to send a message" on Learn-Rails Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railsapps, learn-ruby-on-rails

I keep getting error on "Send Mail" section on the [Learn Ruby on Rails](http://learn-rails.com/learn-ruby-on-rails.html) tutorial.

I have tried to clone https://github.com/RailsApps/learn-rails.git on my local machine but the issue is still here.

Below is my code:

**user_mailer.rb**

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: "do-not-reply@example.com"

  def contact_email(contact)
    @contact = contact
    mail(to: Rails.application.secrets.owner_email, from: @contact.email, :subject => "Website Contact")
  end
end
```

**development.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: Rails.application.secrets.domain_name,
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_username,
    password: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_password
  }
  # ActionMailer Config
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  # Send email in development mode?
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

**secrets.yml**

```
development:
  email_provider_username: <%= ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"] %>
  email_provider_password: <%= ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"] %>
  mailchimp_api_key: <%= ENV["MAILCHIMP_API_KEY"] %>
  mailchimp_list_id: <%= ENV["MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID"] %>
  domain_name: example.com
  owner_email: <%= ENV["OWNER_EMAIL"] %>
```

I have also made sure that the environment variables were set up correctly on .bashrc file.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, and thank you in advance!

Comment: Try hardcoding your Gmail credentials into the secrets.yml file. Don't check it into git, just see if there is any issue with ENV variables.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have tried hardcoding my Gmail credentials into secrets.yml, or user.mailer.rb file, the issue is still here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754979/sending-emails-on-heroku-using-external-smtp/11756507#11756507

Comment: looking like domain name is going example.com or nil

Answer (score 0):

For development, you can use the letter opener gem. Once you send an email it'll automatically open in your default browser.

Add the following to the development section of your Gemfile.

```
gem 'letter_opener'
```

Comment: Thanks zach! I tried it, but the same error is still here.

Comment: Did you bundle install after?

Answer (score 0):

I too was having the identical issue. I tried everything from disabling 2-step verification (Google) to hardcoding my credentials in the secrets.yml with zero success.

I used my outlook.com credentials and it worked perfectly.

Note: this requires a change in **development.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {       
    address : "smtp.live.com"
    # everything else is identical.
}
```

Comment: I think Google changed the Gmail API recently?

Answer (score 0):

Setting it for gmail

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
    ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
      :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :domain => "gmail.com",
      :port => 587, 
      :user_name => "username",
      :password => "password",
      :authentication => :plain,
      :enable_starttls_auto => true,
      :openssl_verify_mode => 'none' 
    }
```

make it true 
  `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` it will tell if any error occurs.

Also try port `25`